# How do I connect to the Airtable API from Power Automate desktop

Tags: airtable, power-automate-desktop

I would like to retrieve data from a base in Airtable from Power Automate Desktop.
I think I would use the Invoke Webservice Action but am not sure how to configure it. Any help would be appreciated. I have the base name, ID, table name, URL (I think) and personal access token,

[image]